# How to append an html element from a string?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Hi,

I have a code like this, first my fixed html which is the container:

```
 <div id="messages"></div>
```

then the javascript that generates its contents:

```
 var post = `<div id="${userid}">${content}</div>`;
 var item = document.createElement('div');
 item.innerHTML = post;
 messages.appendChild(item);
```

the problem with this is that it wrapps each post in a div which I dont need. This should be the output

```
<div id="messages">
 <div id="user45">some content</div>
 <div id="user46">more content</div>
</div>
```

how can I append the content of the string directly to the container without the wrapper?

Thank you.

Comment: Well your code **explicitly** creates the extra `<div>` that you don't want; perhaps you should instead not do that.

Comment: you wrap the post in a div ?

Comment: Is this your full code? I think you're using a loop and appending the item every time

Comment: I did so because I DIDNT KNOW another way, but the guy below already gave me the answer and now I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```js
messages.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', post)
```